# node-red, e-mail Connection timeout

Tags: raspberry-pi, node-red

i have a problem to send mails with node-red. Therefor i used a simple flow with timestamp->template->e-mailnode.

If i trigger a timestamp i get the error message:

> [error] [e-mail:XXX@gmail.com] Error: Connection timeout

I have no idea how i can search the problem on my system?

Here is my list with the npm packages:

```
    pi@raspberrypi ~ $ npm ls
/home/pi
├─┬ activator@1.0.0
│ ├── async@0.2.10
│ └── lodash@3.6.0
├─┬ imap@0.8.14
│ ├─┬ readable-stream@1.1.13
│ │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.1
│ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ ├── isarray@0.0.1
│ │ └── string_decoder@0.10.31
│ └── utf7@1.0.0
├─┬ nodemailer@1.3.2
│ ├─┬ buildmail@1.2.1
│ │ ├── addressparser@0.3.2
│ │ ├── libbase64@0.1.0
│ │ └── libqp@0.1.1
│ ├─┬ hyperquest@1.0.1
│ │ ├─┬ duplexer2@0.0.2
│ │ │ └─┬ readable-stream@1.1.13
│ │ │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.1
│ │ │   ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ │   ├── isarray@0.0.1
│ │ │   └── string_decoder@0.10.31
│ │ └─┬ through2@0.6.3
│ │   ├─┬ readable-stream@1.0.33
│ │   │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.1
│ │   │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │   │ ├── isarray@0.0.1
│ │   │ └── string_decoder@0.10.31
│ │   └── xtend@4.0.0
│ ├─┬ libmime@0.1.7
│ │ ├── iconv-lite@0.4.7
│ │ ├── libbase64@0.1.0
│ │ └── libqp@0.1.1
│ ├─┬ nodemailer-direct-transport@1.0.2
│ │ └── smtp-connection@1.2.0
│ └─┬ nodemailer-smtp-transport@1.0.2
│   ├── nodemailer-wellknown@0.1.5
│   └── smtp-connection@1.2.0
└─┬ nodemailer-ses-transport@1.2.0
  └─┬ aws-sdk@2.1.20
    ├─┬ xml2js@0.2.6
    │ └── sax@0.4.2
    └── xmlbuilder@0.4.2
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If as the error message implies the connection has timed out, it most likely means that the server the email node is configured to talk to is incorrect or not running a SMTP server

Comment: my SMTP setting in the node is

server: smtp.gmail.com
port: <>465
userid: xxx@gmail.com
password: ***

I have to start the server speerate?
How can i the that it runs correctly?

Comment: thanks for help it works. I had a problem with the firewall settings.